# Webview android target='_blank'

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I'm building a App in Android Studio that shows a page in a webview, but I can't seem to get the webview to open pages with target='_blank' in the same webview.
Can this be done?

Currently I have this. As it is now nothing happens when I click a link with target='_blank'
If I change my onCreateWindow I the link open in a external browser, but I don't want tha to happen.

I've tried googling it but can't find a solution.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.dk");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
        {

            WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
            String data = result.getExtra();
            //Context context = view.getContext();
            //Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
            //context.startActivity(browserIntent); // opens in external browser 
            myWebView.loadUrl(data); //don't work!
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

// Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

       return  false;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading method change return type to true;

Comment: If I change shouldOverrideUrlLoading to true I just get a white page.. Nothing loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me.Try this one

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.career_view);
            URL = "http://test.dk/";
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(URL); // Specify the URL to load when the application starts
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                {
                    //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                    setTitle("Loading...");
                    setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
                    // Return the app name after finish loading
                    if(progress == 70)
                        setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            });
            webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setInitialScale(1); // Set the initial zoom scale
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // Initialize zoom controls for your WebView component
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

create private class

```
private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activities.this);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }

            message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
            alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    handler.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are u checked this one or not.

Comment: This seems to open i a browser instead of the webview.

Comment: I had to uncomment the line
            webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
Is that a custom webview client ?

Comment: hey.. Can you give my the code for the SSLTolerentWebViewClient or just tell me what you have overridden in the class?

Comment: SSLTolerentWebViewClient was added are u check it?

Comment: The solution seem to work on most pages but for unknow reason not the one I'm using.. There most be something specific on the page that creates the problem.. I've accepted your answer